# How can I add a single empty row after a certain number of rows from a txt

Tags: text-formatting

This is the text file `Drives.txt`:

```
    Slot Number              : 0   
    Drive's position         : DiskGroup 0  
    Media Error Count        : 0   
    Other Error Count        : 0   
    Predictive Failure Count : 0   
    Raw Size                 : 745.211 GB [0x5d26ceb0 Sectors]
    Firmware state           : Online, Spun Up 
    Inquiry Data             : WDC WUSTR6480ASS200 K95DV6X3NG2A 
    Foreign State            : None   
    Media Type               : Solid State Device 
    Drive Temperature        : 27C (80.60 F) 
    Drive S.M.A.R.T alert    : No
    Slot Number              : 1   
    Drive's position         : DiskGroup 0  
    Media Error Count        : 0   
    Other Error Count        : 0   
    Predictive Failure Count : 0   
    Raw Size                 : 745.211 GB [0x5d26ceb0 Sectors]
    Firmware state           : Online, Spun Up 
    Inquiry Data             : WDC WUSTR6480ASS200 K95DV6X3NG2A 
    Foreign State            : None   
    Media Type               : Solid State Device 
    Drive Temperature        : 27C (80.60 F) 
    Drive S.M.A.R.T alert    : No
    Slot Number              : 2   
    Drive's position         : DiskGroup 0  
    Media Error Count        : 0   
    Other Error Count        : 0   
    Predictive Failure Count : 0   
    Raw Size                 : 745.211 GB [0x5d26ceb0 Sectors]
    Firmware state           : Online, Spun Up 
    Inquiry Data             : WDC WUSTR6480ASS200 K95DV6X3NG2A 
    Foreign State            : None   
    Media Type               : Solid State Device 
    Drive Temperature        : 27C (80.60 F) 
    Drive S.M.A.R.T alert    : No
```

I would like add an empty line after every 12th line
(i.e., the 12th line, the 24th, the 36th, etc.),
so there will be a space between each drive that has been diagnosed.
How can I do it? I want to implement it in a bash script.

The output has to look like this:

```
Slot Number              : 0   
Drive's position         : DiskGroup 0  
Media Error Count        : 0   
Other Error Count        : 0   
Predictive Failure Count : 0   
Raw Size                 : 745.211 GB [0x5d26ceb0 Sectors]
Firmware state           : Online, Spun Up 
Inquiry Data             : WDC WUSTR6480ASS200 K95DV6X3NG2A 
Foreign State            : None   
Media Type               : Solid State Device 
Drive Temperature        : 27C (80.60 F) 
Drive S.M.A.R.T alert    : No

Slot Number              : 1   
Drive's position         : DiskGroup 0  
Media Error Count        : 0   
Other Error Count        : 0   
Predictive Failure Count : 0   
Raw Size                 : 745.211 GB [0x5d26ceb0 Sectors]
Firmware state           : Online, Spun Up 
Inquiry Data             : WDC WUSTR6480ASS200 K95DV6X3NG2A 
Foreign State            : None   
Media Type               : Solid State Device 
Drive Temperature        : 27C (80.60 F) 
Drive S.M.A.R.T alert    : No

Slot Number              : 2   
Drive's position         : DiskGroup 0  
Media Error Count        : 0   
Other Error Count        : 0   
Predictive Failure Count : 0   
Raw Size                 : 745.211 GB [0x5d26ceb0 Sectors]
Firmware state           : Online, Spun Up 
Inquiry Data             : WDC WUSTR6480ASS200 K95DV6X3NG2A 
Foreign State            : None   
Media Type               : Solid State Device 
Drive Temperature        : 27C (80.60 F) 
Drive S.M.A.R.T alert    : No
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a natural fit for [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```bsh
awk '{print} NR % 12 == 0 {print ""}' Drives.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Type

```
sed '12~12a\
' Drives.txt
```

(yes; that’s two separate lines;
the shell will issue a `>` prompt after you enter the first one), or

```
sed -e '12~12a\' -e '' Drives.txt
```

The `M~N` addressing mode
is an extension to GNU sed that means
“do the following command on line *`M`*
and every `N`th line after that”. 
The `a` command in sed means “append a line”. 
Normally you would provide text to be inserted;
since you want blank lines, I used `''`.

As steeldriver points out, you could also use `0~12`. 
Since there is no 0th line, it effectively starts at line 12.

Answer (score 2):

With any `sed` implementation, you can add a newline after the `alert :` line by appending the (empty) hold space with `G`:

```
sed '/alert *:/G' Drives.txt
```

If you dislike the empty line at the end of the file, then for the last line (address `$`) `P`rint only the part before the newline, then `d`elete the line:

```
sed '/alert *:/G;$P;$d' Drives.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `sed` (a solution that don't rely on lines number but on the string `Slot Number` to identify a section):

```
sed '1!s/^ *Slot Number/\n&/' test
```

---

GNU `sed` (Using a GNU `sed` features called [`first step`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-addresses)):

```
sed '0~12s/$/\n/' test
```

---

As suggested by **@steeldriver** the above can be shortened to :

```
sed '0~12G' test
```

Comment: or perhaps more idiomatically `sed '0~12G'`

Comment: @steeldriver post it as an answers, it will be the shortest!

Comment: Feel free to add it as an alternate

Comment: Your first version uses `\n` in the replacement string, which is undefined by POSIX and will insert the letter `n` with most `sed` implementations. To make it portable, use a backslash followed by an actual newline.

Comment: Thank you! sed '0~12G' worked perfect for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR%12 == 0 {$0=$0"\n"}1' file.txt
```

output

```
  Slot Number              : 0   
    Drive's position         : DiskGroup 0  
    Media Error Count        : 0   
    Other Error Count        : 0   
    Predictive Failure Count : 0   
    Raw Size                 : 745.211 GB [0x5d26ceb0 Sectors]
    Firmware state           : Online, Spun Up 
    Inquiry Data             : WDC WUSTR6480ASS200 K95DV6X3NG2A 
    Foreign State            : None   
    Media Type               : Solid State Device 
    Drive Temperature        : 27C (80.60 F) 
    Drive S.M.A.R.T alert    : No

    Slot Number              : 1   
    Drive's position         : DiskGroup 0  
    Media Error Count        : 0   
    Other Error Count        : 0   
    Predictive Failure Count : 0   
    Raw Size                 : 745.211 GB [0x5d26ceb0 Sectors]
    Firmware state           : Online, Spun Up 
    Inquiry Data             : WDC WUSTR6480ASS200 K95DV6X3NG2A 
    Foreign State            : None   
    Media Type               : Solid State Device 
    Drive Temperature        : 27C (80.60 F) 
    Drive S.M.A.R.T alert    : No

    Slot Number              : 2   
    Drive's position         : DiskGroup 0  
    Media Error Count        : 0   
    Other Error Count        : 0   
    Predictive Failure Count : 0   
    Raw Size                 : 745.211 GB [0x5d26ceb0 Sectors]
    Firmware state           : Online, Spun Up 
    Inquiry Data             : WDC WUSTR6480ASS200 K95DV6X3NG2A 
    Foreign State            : None   
    Media Type               : Solid State Device 
    Drive Temperature        : 27C (80.60 F) 
    Drive S.M.A.R.T alert    : No
```